# ionic framework slides component "loop" option

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am currently developing an application using Ionic-Angular.
for slides I am using ionic 4 ion-slides component and every thing works fine but I was looking for a way to loop the slides so that user can have swipe with no locking at the end of array
according to ionic docs => [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#properties)

and [Swiper API](https://swiperjs.com/api/)

I can achieve this by using loop property in options, so I followed the instruction but it doesn't seem to work and the slide locks at the end of the array
My HtMl code is:

```
<ion-slides #theSlides [options]="slideOpts"   id="peerSlide">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let peer of peers;let i = index">
       <img id="{{'x' + i}}" class="peerIcon" [src]="peer.icon" >
     </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<img class="nextIcon" src="../../assets/imgs/nextIcon/nextIcon@3x.png" (click)="moveToNext(theSlides)">
<img class="prevIcon" src="../../assets/imgs/prevIcon/prevIcon@3x.png" (click)="moveToPrev(theSlides)">
```

and my .ts file:

```
export class LivePage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('theSlides' , {  static: true }) slides: IonSlides;
 
  slideOpts = {
  loop: true,
   };

  ...
  moveToNext(slides) {
   slides.slideNext()
  }
  moveToPrev(slides) {
   slides.slidePrev()
  }
 }
```

I appreciate if you can tell what is wrong here with my code thank you.

Update: when i try it with out ngFor the loop will work fine but with ngFor it doesn't

Comment: Loop is working in my app. Check documentation. 1> https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/master/src/demos/api/slides/index.html      2> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#properties

Comment: hi, im using the same documentation but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you add this part to stackblitz?

Comment: im afraid i cant the peer object comes from server in my app

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me with same code ("@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0")
try to update your dependancies

Comment: hi, my ionic version is 5.4.16 now and its updated but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: you have tried with an empty project to ensure that all work fine

Comment: i tried it with a blank new app and turned out without ngFor loop it works fine but when i add ngfor like my code on the top it stops working

Comment: try to use trackBy method in ngFor directive